# electron-rebuild fails for sqlite3

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, npm, electron, electron-rebuild

**I want to use sqlite in my electron application with reactjs so I flow this guid https://www.aljaiban.com/post/setting-up-electron-with-sqlite-on-windows**

- "electron": "^7.1.2"
- "electron-builder": "^21.2.0"
- "electron-rebuild": "^1.10.0"
- "sqlite": "^3.0.3"

but when I want to rebuild the sqlite3 with electron-rebuild it show me this message error :

```
× Rebuild Failed
An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
gyp info using node@12.15.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.14 found at "C:\Python27\python.exe"
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/node-v8.0.0-headers.tar.gz     
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/node-v8.0.0-headers.tar.gz     
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp info find VS using VS2015 (14.0) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\.electron-gyp\\8.0.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',       
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\yousra\\.electron-gyp\\8.0.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\yousra\\\\.electron-gyp\\\\8.0.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
G�n�ration des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la g�n�ration en parall�le, ajoutez le commutateur "/m".
C:\Users\yousra\Desktop\ATECH\gs_location_voiture\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: Le projet import� "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" est introuvable. V�rifiez que le chemin d'acc�s dans la d�claration <Import> est correct et que le fichier existe 
sur le disque.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 
1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)       
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=8.0.0" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v8.0-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.1.1/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v8.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\yousra\Desktop\ATECH\gs_location_voiture\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1

Error: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
gyp info using node@12.15.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.14 found at "C:\Python27\python.exe"
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/node-v8.0.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/node-v8.0.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http GET https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://electronjs.org/headers/v8.0.0/win-arm64/node.lib
gyp info find VS using VS2015 (14.0) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\.electron-gyp\\8.0.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',       
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\yousra\\.electron-gyp\\8.0.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\yousra\\\\.electron-gyp\\\\8.0.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
G�n�ration des projets individuellement dans cette solution. Pour activer la g�n�ration en parall�le, ajoutez le commutateur "/m".
C:\Users\yousra\Desktop\ATECH\gs_location_voiture\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: Le projet import� "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" est introuvable. V�rifiez que le chemin d'acc�s dans la d�claration <Import> est correct et que le fichier existe 
sur le disque.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 
1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)       
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\yousra\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=8.0.0" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\yousra\\Desktop\\ATECH\\gs_location_voiture\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v8.0-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.1.1/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v8.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\yousra\Desktop\ATECH\gs_location_voiture\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:267:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:205:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:156:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:92:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:72:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:92:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:72:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:242:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:205:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\yousra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:143:22)
```

Thanks.